# Lost data stored in localStorage issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, undefined

I have a `token` stored in `localStorage`, I have also a method that verifies if the token is correct or not, as you can see in this code:

```
let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
console.log(token);

if ( !token )
{
    return null;
}

const parts = token.split('.');

if ( parts.length !== 3 )
{
    throw new Error('error');
}
....
```

if the token is `undefined` I will return null, else continue the verification.

There are two issues I can't understand:

- Why did I lose the token from the localStorage when I refresh the page
- Why does the `if ( !token )` return false when `token` is `undefined`, the first console.log return undefined, but my method continues to `const parts = token.split('.');`.

Comment: There is no sign of local storage in your code snippet.

Comment: Do check that you have not stored `undefined` string as the value of localStorage 

Comment: You should consider verification "Failed" by default. And only make it successful when verification passed.

Comment: And you shouldn't store tokens in local storage. It's a security issue.

Comment: @Ashish no I stored the token in the local storage, when I don't refresh the page the token is logged correctly, but when I refresh the page I get undefined

Comment: @VladDX ok, let us not talk about the localstorage, but why `if (!token)` return false when the token is undefined!

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter because empty string, null or undefined will return false

Comment: Are you sure your key is named token ? `localStorage.setItem('token', yourdata); `

Comment: @Sayf-Eddine Just for curiosity, I tried `console.log('token: ' + token + ' - ' + (token === undefined || token === '' || token === null));` and it returns `token: undefined - false`

Comment: @Sayf-Eddine and yes I use `set token(token: string)
    {
        localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local storage work only with strings.

> MDN: Window.localStorage
>
> The keys and the values stored with localStorage are always in the UTF-16 DOMString format, which uses two bytes per character. As with objects, integer keys are automatically converted to strings.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

So, every value is serialized as a string.

```js
localStorage.setItem('token', undefined);
let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
console.log(token);
console.log(typeof(token));
```

Prints out in the console:

```
undefined
string
```

**Conclusions**:

1. Don't store `null` and `undefined` in Local Storage.
2. When validating the value from Local Storage, always treat it as a `string` value.

---

Notes:

1. Validation should return `false` by default. And only in case of success should return `true`.
2. You shouldn't store any tokens in Local Storage, it's not secure.
3. You shouldn't validate anything on a client as the validation logic can be easily manipulated.

Comment: Ok, I will follow these steps, I want the last thing, what is the best practice to store tokens then?

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter here you can see 

https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/#store-jwts-securely

Comment: For the future, I followed my code, and effectively, I found: when I refresh the page I refresh the token, and here I set undefined instead of the correct value, thank you for your answer I appreciate it

Comment: @Doesn'tMatter, check out my SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650692/where-to-store-the-refresh-token-on-the-client/57826596#57826596